# REST Webservice Java- Tomcat error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I am completely new in JAVA RESTful Web services. I tried to implement a simple REST service but getting the error shown down below.

[The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wYgA.png)

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>RESTfulDemo</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Next is my testing class: V1_Status

```
@Path("/v1/status")
public class V1_Status
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle()
    {
        return "<p>Java Web Services</p>";
    }
}
```

[Here is my Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmPeJ.png)

If I just type localhost address it gives me the index.jsp file alright. But do not know why the above mentioned is being shown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter jersey.config.server.provider.packages defines in which package Jersey will look for the web service classes.
Looks like the value of this property is wrong in your case. Provide the package in which your  V1_Status exists.

Comment: ...Bro thanks for the reply, but i tried what you suggested. Still same error.